Cannot configure CMake with CUDA when using MSVC with Ninja
Environment:
VS2019 with CUDA 11.3 trying to compile with Ninja generator instead(VS generator works fine).
Relevant CMake file section:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

##########################################
# Toolchain
##########################################


set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION "10.0.22621.0")
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR "AMD64")
set(CMAKE_VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET_HOST_ARCHITECTURE "x64")
set(CMAKE_VS_VERSION_RANGE "[16.0,17.0)")
set(VS_PLATFORM_TOOLSET_VERSION "14.29.30133") #For v142 VS2019
set(CMAKE_VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION "10.0.26100.0")
if(DEFINED ENV{CUDA_PATH})
    set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER "$ENV{CUDA_PATH}/bin/nvcc.exe")
endif()

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/toolchains/Windows.MSVC.toolchain.cmake)

##########################################
# Project
##########################################
project(Foo
  LANGUAGES C CXX CUDA
)

CMake during enable_language(CUDA) seems to run nvcc compile to get the version of CUDA compiler.
Following is same build command used in CMake.
nvcc.exe --keep --keep-dir tmp -ccbin="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" -v .\CMakeCUDACompilerId.cu

Running this with VS2019 environment shell, I get same error as CMake which is:
PS C:\TSS\out\build\windows-msvc-x64\CMakeFiles\3.30.1\CompilerIdCUDA> nvcc.exe --keep --keep-dir tmp -ccbin="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" -v .\CMakeCUDACompilerId.cu
#$ C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/../../../../../../../VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars64.bat

C:\TSS\out\build\windows-msvc-x64\CMakeFiles\3.30.1\CompilerIdCUDA>call "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/../../../../../../../VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars64.bat"
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.11.39
** Copyright (c) 2021 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
#$ AF_PATH=C:\Program Files\ArrayFire\v3
#$ AF_PATH_v3=C:\Program Files\ArrayFire\v3
#$ ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
#$ APPDATA=C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming
#$ ASGLMD_LICENSE_FILE=C:\ProgramData\Thermo Fisher Scientific\Thermo Scientific License Manager\Share\licenseFile.txt;27001@DESKTOP-1CSUU27
#$ CommandPromptType=Native
#$ CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
#$ CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
#$ CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
#$ COMPUTERNAME=SW-WBKANG-WORK
#$ ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
#$ CUDACXX=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin\nvcc.exe
#$ CUDATOOLKITDIR=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3
#$ CUDA_PATH_V11_3=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3
#$ DevEnvDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\
#$ DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
#$ EFC_9864=1
#$ ExtensionSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs
#$ FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=Internet Explorer
#$ FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=Default
#$ Framework40Version=v4.0
#$ FrameworkDir=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\
#$ FrameworkDir32=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\
#$ FrameworkDir64=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\
#$ FrameworkVersion=v4.0.30319
#$ FrameworkVersion32=v4.0.30319
#$ FrameworkVersion64=v4.0.30319
#$ GGML_CUDA_ENABLE_UNIFIED_MEMORY=1
#$ HOMEDRIVE=C:
#$ HOMEPATH=\Users\ADMIN
#$ INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.26100.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.26100.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.26100.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.26100.0\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.26100.0\cppwinrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.26100.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.26100.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.26100.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.26100.0\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.26100.0\cppwinrt
#$ LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.26100.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.26100.0\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\lib\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.26100.0\ucrt\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.26100.0\um\x86
#$ LIBPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x86\store\references;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.26100.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.26100.0;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\lib\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x86\store\references;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.26100.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.26100.0;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
#$ LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local
#$ LOGONSERVER=\\SW-WBKANG-WORK
#$ MCSLMD_LICENSE_FILE=C:\ProgramData\Thermo Fisher Scientific\Thermo Scientific License Manager\Share\licenseFile.txt;27001@DESKTOP-1CSUU27
#$ NETFXSDKDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\
#$ NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=28
#$ NVCUDASAMPLES11_3_ROOT=C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v11.3
#$ NVCUDASAMPLES_ROOT=C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v11.3
#$ NVTOOLSEXT_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\
#$ OIVARCH=arch-Windows-x86_64-msvc17-Release
#$ OIVHOME=C:\OIV2024
#$ OIV_LICENSE_FILE=C:\OIV2024\License\password.dat
#$ OneDrive=C:\Users\ADMIN\OneDrive - Tomocube
#$ OneDriveCommercial=C:\Users\ADMIN\OneDrive - Tomocube
#$ OS=Windows_NT
#$ Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\devinit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.26100.0\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\\MSBuild\Current\Bin;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\devinit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.26100.0\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\\MSBuild\Current\Bin;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\libnvvp;;C:\TomoPython\Scripts\;C:\TomoPython\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Bandizip\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\ArrayFire\v3\lib;C:\MATLAB\v910\runtime\win64;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Tailscale\;C:\clang\clang+llvm-18.1.8-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\sources\ninja;C:\tools\WezTerm;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2021.1.0\;C:\Users\ADMIN\.cargo\bin;C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ADMIN\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\Llvm\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja
#$ PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW;.CPL
#$ Platform=x64
#$ PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
#$ PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 183 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
#$ PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
#$ PROCESSOR_REVISION=b701
#$ ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
#$ ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
#$ ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
#$ ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
#$ PROMPT=$P$G
#$ PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Users\ADMIN\OneDrive - Tomocube\문서\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
#$ PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
#$ PYTHONHOME=C:\TomoPython
#$ SESSIONNAME=Console
#$ SystemDrive=C:
#$ SystemRoot=C:\Windows
#$ TLM_EXE=C:\Program Files\Thermo Scientific License Manager\Thermo Scientific License Manager.exe
#$ UCRTVersion=10.0.26100.0
#$ UniversalCRTSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
#$ USERDOMAIN=SW-WBKANG-WORK
#$ USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=SW-WBKANG-WORK
#$ USERNAME=ADMIN
#$ USERPROFILE=C:\Users\ADMIN
#$ VCIDEInstallDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\
#$ VCINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\
#$ VCToolsInstallDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\
#$ VCToolsRedistDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.29.30133\
#$ VCToolsVersion=14.29.30133
#$ VisualStudioVersion=16.0
#$ VS140COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\
#$ VS160COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\
#$ VSCMD_ARG_app_plat=Desktop
#$ VSCMD_ARG_HOST_ARCH=x64
#$ VSCMD_ARG_TGT_ARCH=x64
#$ VSCMD_VER=16.11.39
#$ VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\
#$ windir=C:\Windows
#$ WindowsLibPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.26100.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.26100.0
#$ WindowsSdkBinPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\
#$ WindowsSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
#$ WindowsSDKLibVersion=10.0.26100.0\
#$ WindowsSdkVerBinPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.26100.0\
#$ WindowsSDKVersion=10.0.26100.0\
#$ WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\
#$ WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\
#$ ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN=1
#$ __devinit_path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\devinit\devinit.exe
#$ __DOTNET_ADD_32BIT=1
#$ __DOTNET_ADD_64BIT=1
#$ __DOTNET_PREFERRED_BITNESS=64
#$ __VSCMD_PREINIT_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\libnvvp;;C:\TomoPython\Scripts\;C:\TomoPython\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Bandizip\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\ArrayFire\v3\lib;C:\MATLAB\v910\runtime\win64;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Tailscale\;C:\clang\clang+llvm-18.1.8-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\sources\ninja;C:\tools\WezTerm;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2021.1.0\;C:\Users\ADMIN\.cargo\bin;C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ADMIN\.dotnet\tools
#$ __VSCMD_PREINIT_VCToolsVersion=14.29.30133
#$ __VSCMD_PREINIT_VS160COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\
#$ __VSCMD_script_err_count=0
#$ PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\devinit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.26100.0\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\\MSBuild\Current\Bin;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\devinit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.26100.0\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\\MSBuild\Current\Bin;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\libnvvp;;C:\TomoPython\Scripts\;C:\TomoPython\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Bandizip\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\ArrayFire\v3\lib;C:\MATLAB\v910\runtime\win64;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Tailscale\;C:\clang\clang+llvm-18.1.8-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\sources\ninja;C:\tools\WezTerm;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2021.1.0\;C:\Users\ADMIN\.cargo\bin;C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ADMIN\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\Llvm\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja
#$ _NVVM_BRANCH_=nvvm
#$ _SPACE_=
#$ _CUDART_=cudart
#$ _HERE_=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin
#$ _THERE_=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin
#$ _TARGET_SIZE_=
#$ _TARGET_DIR_=
#$ _TARGET_SIZE_=64
#$ _WIN_PLATFORM_=x64
#$ TOP=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin/..
#$ NVVMIR_LIBRARY_DIR=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin/../nvvm/libdevice
#$ PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin/../nvvm/bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin/../lib;C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\devinit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.26100.0\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\\MSBuild\Current\Bin;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\devinit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.26100.0\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\\MSBuild\Current\Bin;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\libnvvp;;C:\TomoPython\Scripts\;C:\TomoPython\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Bandizip\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\ArrayFire\v3\lib;C:\MATLAB\v910\runtime\win64;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Tailscale\;C:\clang\clang+llvm-18.1.8-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\sources\ninja;C:\tools\WezTerm;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2021.1.0\;C:\Users\ADMIN\.cargo\bin;C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ADMIN\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\Llvm\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja
#$ INCLUDES="-IC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin/../include"
#$ LIBRARIES=  "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin/../lib/x64"
#$ CUDAFE_FLAGS=
#$ PTXAS_FLAGS=
#$ erase tmp/a_dlink.reg.c
CMakeCUDACompilerId.cu
#$ cl.exe @"tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.cpp1.ii.res" > "tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.cpp1.ii"
CMakeCUDACompilerId.cu
#$ cicc --microsoft_version=1929 --msvc_target_version=1929 --compiler_bindir "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/../../../../../../.." --sdk_dir "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/" --orig_src_file_name "./CMakeCUDACompilerId.cu" --allow_managed  -arch compute_52 -m64 --no-version-ident -ftz=0 -prec_div=1 -prec_sqrt=1 -fmad=1 --include_file_name "CMakeCUDACompilerId.fatbin.c" -tused --gen_module_id_file --module_id_file_name "tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.module_id" --gen_c_file_name "tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.cudafe1.c" --stub_file_name "tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.cudafe1.stub.c" --gen_device_file_name "tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.cudafe1.gpu"  "tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.cpp1.ii" -o "tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.ptx"
#$ ptxas -arch=sm_52 -m64 "tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.ptx"  -o "tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.sm_52.cubin"
#$ fatbinary --create="tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.fatbin" -64 --cicc-cmdline="-ftz=0 -prec_div=1 -prec_sqrt=1 -fmad=1 " "--image3=kind=elf,sm=52,file=tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.sm_52.cubin" "--image3=kind=ptx,sm=52,file=tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.ptx" --embedded-fatbin="tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.fatbin.c"
#$ cl.exe @"tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.cpp4.ii.res" > "tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.cpp4.ii"
CMakeCUDACompilerId.cu
#$ cudafe++ --microsoft_version=1929 --msvc_target_version=1929 --compiler_bindir "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/../../../../../../.." --sdk_dir "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/" --orig_src_file_name "./CMakeCUDACompilerId.cu" --allow_managed --m64 --parse_templates --gen_c_file_name "tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.cudafe1.cpp" --stub_file_name "CMakeCUDACompilerId.cudafe1.stub.c" --module_id_file_name "tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.module_id" "tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.cpp4.ii"
#$ cl.exe @"tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.obj.res" -Fo"tmp/CMakeCUDACompilerId.obj"
CMakeCUDACompilerId.cudafe1.cpp
#$ nvlink -optf "tmp/a_dlink.sm_52.cubin.optf"
#$ fatbinary --create="tmp/a_dlink.fatbin" -64 --cicc-cmdline="-ftz=0 -prec_div=1 -prec_sqrt=1 -fmad=1 " -link "--image3=kind=elf,sm=52,file=tmp/a_dlink.sm_52.cubin" --embedded-fatbin="tmp/a_dlink.fatbin.c"
#$ cl.exe @"tmp/a_dlink.obj.res" -Fo"tmp/a_dlink.obj"
link.stub
#$ cl.exe @"tmp/a.exe.res" -Fe"a.exe"
   Creating library a.lib and object a.exp
libucrt.lib(checkcfg.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _guard_check_icall_$fo$
a.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
# --error 0x2 --

I've tried followings:

Remove all other versions of NVIDIA GPU toolkit for CUDA except 11.3. Reinstall 11.3 version, reboot.
Use following toolchain: https://github.com/MarkSchofield/WindowsToolchain/blob/main/Windows.MSVC.toolchain.cmake still same issue.


I solved this by: changing windows toolkit to 10.0.22621.0 version instead of 10.0.26100.0
